# Open tile map source in Qgis

Tags: qgis, xml

I'm trying to open this xml source in Qgis:
http://webgis.regione.sardegna.it/tms/ortofoto1977_EPSG3003/tilemapresource.xml
but I see only a corrupted image.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think the tilemapservice= is wrong. It should be something like <TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://webgis.regione.sardegna.it/tms/ortofoto1977_EPSG3003">

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your file does not contain any header information:
[image: xml1]

In order to read XML correctly, qgis needs to be able to read the version and document type of your XML document:

Sample XML from Google Search of "XML Example".  Note the XML version and DOCTYPE that are included in the first two lines.

[image: xml2]